# How can i display my firebase data on my text? Flutter

Tags: android, ios, database, flutter, firebase

how can i display my firebase data on my text view in flutter? i have made a database where i store the users name in. What i want to do now is display that name from my database in firebase to my textview. i can't seem to figure it out.

this is my code for the textview

```
  return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: size.height * 1,
            decoration: BoxDecoration (gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
          hexStringToColor("FFBEC8"),
          hexStringToColor("fe98a8"),
          hexStringToColor("FC98A7"),
          hexStringToColor("#FF8799")
        ]
          ))),
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 64,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 29,
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                              'assets/logo.png'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 16,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                        'gfffff',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20),
                            ),

                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),

                  ),
```

i don't know if this is enought code for you to know how i stored it

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Userdata").doc(value.user!.uid).set({"name": _userNameTextController.text});

Comment: Can you share how you've saved data on firestore?

Comment: i don't know if this is enought code  for you to know how i stored it FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Userdata").doc(value.user!.uid).set({"name": _userNameTextController.text});

Comment: try https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data